# Some fundamental confusion in linear differential equation in thinking about the space of solution as a space of functions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Sorry I might have kind of a dumb question here.

Let $ f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and consider a linear differential equations of the form 
$$ a_{n}f^{(n)} + a_{n-1} f^{(n-1)} + ... + a_{2} f^{(2)} + a_1 f^{(1)}+a_0f= 0$$
one could think of the space of solutions as the kernal of the linear operator
$$a_{n}D^n + a_{n-1}D^{n-1}+...+a_{2}D^2 + a_{1}D + a_{0} $$
which acts on the space of all $ n $-th order differentiable functions. However, when thinking about a system of linear differential equations of the form
$$ \dot{f} = Af $$ 
where $ f $ is an $ n $-th dimensional vector $ \Big( f_{1}(t), .. f_{n}(t) \Big) $ and $ A $ is an $ n \times n $ matrix I get kind of confused. So the question is simple: does $A$ in this case corresponds to any linear operator $T$ acting on any space that is not $\mathbb{R}^{n}$? Or is it right for me to think of $A$ geometrically as an endomorphism on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ in its own right. Cause what happen is that I am aware that every linear operator defined on arbitrary vector space over $\mathbb{K}$ can be represented isomorphically as a matrix defined on the coordinates. But in this case think it doesn't seems likely but the then the theory I stated in the very beginning gives me some doubt. So basically I am asking if this matrix $A$ has anything to do with the general theory in terms of the differential operator $D$ or am I just too blind to see it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take the space $L$ of $C^{\infty}$ $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$.  The matrix $A$ induces a linear endomorphism $\mathcal{A}$ on $L$ by $(\mathcal{A}f)(t) := A f(t)$, and let $D$ be defined as $(Df)(t) := f'(t)$.  Then solutions of $\dot{f} = A f$ are just elements of the kernel of $D - \mathcal{A}$.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I would like to know whether for every $t$, $ A $ is simply a linear transformation in the real space, one that we could picture geometrically. Or perhaps $A$ represents a linear operator that is not defined in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. So that $A$ is a coordinate transformation of any sort.

Comment: $A$ is a linear operator from $\mathbb{R}^n$ into itself, not a coordinate transformation.  If you know some differential topology, a vector field (not necessarily linear) on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a mapping assigning to each $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ a vector in the tangent space $T_{x}\mathbb{R}^n$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ over $x$.  As those tangent spaces can be identified with $\mathbb{R}^n$, we can write the vector field as a function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ into itself.  If you don't, you can imagine a vector field as a mapping assigning to each _point_ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ some _vector_ bound at $x$.

Comment: And in the case of a _linear_ vector field, that assignment happens to be linear.  And if we take the same basis in the space of _points_ (the manifold) and in the space of _vectors_ (on which the tangent spaces are modeled) we can express the linear operator as an $n$ by $n$ matrix.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you!

Comment: Incidentally, you can look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2705359/what-is-the-derivative-of-a-vector-field-in-a-manifold.